# VS Code syntax bug - readonly property is highlighted as error

Tags: php, class

I'm following a php tutorial, in this video the tutor used a 'readonly' property when he declared a variable, but when I did this, it was highlighted as red. When I hover cursor over the 'readonly' property, VS Code displays the following error:

> ('VariableName' expected.php ')' expected.php '{' expected.php)

My code:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Users\Application\Query\FindUserByEmail;

use App\Shared\Application\Query\QueryInterface;

class FindUserByEmailQuery implements QueryInterface
{
  public function __construct(public readonly string $email) {}
}
```

I get this error not only in this particular class, but in every other class in __construct() function where I type 'readonly'. Changing 'public' to 'private' property also doesn't work. The tutor was working in PHPStorm IDE and no errors were received.

[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ToJg.png)

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? This is a PHP8.1 feature iirc

Comment: @brombeer I use 8.1 in the project, what should I do?

Comment: Have you made sure that VSCode is set to use 8.1 too? Are you using intelephense? Not using 8.1, but there's a settings in `Settings › Extensions › intelephense › Intelephense › Environment: PHP Version`, see if that is set to 8.1, not sure if that fixes it though